# Issue while fetching app details on lasso server instance

Tags: apache, lasso-lang

I am getting following error(error snapshot attached below) while trying to access LassoApps section under lasso server instance. I am using lasso 9.2 with LassoLab and Apache Web server 2.2 on a windows 8 machine.

error in lasso app section:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHAeO.png]

Also, here is the entry in lassospitfire.out.txt file. Hope this could help in someway.

```
211:22 http_server.lasso
211:22 http_server.lasso
101:4 http_server.lasso
440:10 lassospitfire.lasso
251:13 lassospitfire.lasso
473:9 http_server.lasso
471:4 http_server.lasso
471:4 http_server.lasso
465:4 http_server.lasso
464:16 http_server.lasso
A Failure: 995 The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread            exit or an application request.
```

Need assistance in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like Lasso 9.3. Make sure you're using the latest Windows build, and if it still doesn't work, try removing LJAPI.dll from the main LassoModules folder.

Comment: thanks. Could you provide me details of exact version to use on a windows 8 machine. I installed various versions of it but did not work out well.